# What causes periodic noise with LM386 amplifier

Tags: audio, noise, lm386

I am trying to use a LM386 to amplify an audio signal so that I can listen to it using a speaker. I am using the recommended circuit from the data sheet:

[image: LM386 circuit]

When I connect my audio source to the input, I am able to hear the sound in the speaker, but there is a low-frequency noise in the background. If I connect the input to the ground, that noise persists, which indicates that the noise does not come from the input.

Also, the circuit is powered by a 9V battery, which eliminates the power supply as a suspect.

Using an oscilloscope, I connected the (grounded) input to channel 1 and the output to channel 2. As can be seen in the picture below, there is a periodic spike with a frequency of about 15 Hz.

[image]

**What could be causing this periodic signal?**

I admit that it is likely that I made a mistake in my connections, but this is a rather simple circuit, and I already triple-checked every connection.

Comment: Do you have a fairly large decoupling capacitor (ca. 100uF) on the LM386? That's something that was always advised for undergrad labs.

Comment: @user2943160 Isn't that what the 250uF capacitor shown in the schematic is?

Comment: No, that is the output decoupling. To clarify: I was suggesting power supply decoupling. At least +V to -V, or both +V to ground and -V to ground (check polarity).

Comment: What other devices/circuitry are in your circuit i.e. powered off the battery?

Comment: I'd agree - definitely add a decoupling capacitor and see if that changes anything. Also try running it off a AC -> DC power adapter if you can. And try moving it somewhere else - I've had op-amps and similar audio circuits pick up transmissions before (sometimes in the unfortunate form of rush limbaugh!).

Comment: How is the grounding?  If the circuit is on a breadboard, it is probably not very good.  I would think small differences in grounding resistance would introduce amplified waveforms.  I have done many circuits on breadboards where weak grounding causes fluctuations but on a nice PCB everything is good.

Comment: The circuit is on a breadboard, yes. I will try to make the circuit on a PCB. @user2943160, I can try to add a decoupling capacitors, but I expected that with a battery it would not be necessary. Am I mistaken?

Comment: @uint128_t, the battery is also powering a voltage regulator that supplies a microcontroller and a SD card. I will try to remove that and see if the noise disappears.

Comment: @AntoineAubry: yes, you should still add the capacitors. Power supply decoupling is for both source->load and load->source decoupling, particularly for high-speed or high-power (relatively speaking) systems. You should be able to get acceptable performance from a LM386 on a solderless breadboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a 100uF decoupling capacitor as suggested in the comments significantly reduced the noise. I also found that the noise was being induced by a MCU that was blinking a led and was powered by the same battery.

Answer (score 2):

**TROUBLESHOOTING HINT:** When troubleshooting, **ALWAYS** start with the power supplies. Using an oscilloscope (not a multimeter), observe the power supply voltage at the device under test's (DUT) power pins. (In your case the DUT would be the LM386 audio amplifier IC.) It is VERY IMPORTANT that you test the voltage at the DUT's power pins and not at some other location on the circuit assembly.

> Also, the circuit is powered by a 9V battery, which eliminates the
>   power supply as a suspect.

Actually, your 9 Volt battery is your prime suspect. Those batteries are not suitable for driving loads like a microcontroller development board, and SD card hardware, and audio amplifier with a speaker, etc. A 9 Volt alkaline battery has relatively high internal resistance, low amp-hour (energy storage) capacity, and other limitations that make it an undesirable power source for the system you've described.